# Using virtualenvwrapper with non-system version of python

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am attempting to use virtualenvwrapper to create a virtual environment using a specific local python interpreter:

```
mkvirtualenv -p /home/nelse003/software/ccp4-linux64-2016-10-22-0115/libexec/python2.7 ccp4-python-env`
```

But it fails to create the virtual environment:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /home/nelse003/software/ccp4-linux64-2016-10-22-0115/libexec/python2.7
New python executable in /home/nelse003/.virtualenvs/ccp4-python-env/bin/python2.7
Not overwriting existing python script /home/nelse003/.virtualenvs/ccp4-python-env/bin/python (you must use /home/nelse003/.virtualenvs/ccp4-python-env/bin/python2.7)`
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...`
Complete output from command /home/nelse003/.virt...on-env/bin/python2.7 - setuptools pip wheel:`
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/utils/glibc.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/home/nelse003/software/ccp4-linux64-2016-10-22-0115/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: /home/nelse003/.virtualenvs/ccp4-python-env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromUnicode`
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2328, in <module>
main()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
download=download,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
% (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/nelse003/.virt...on-env/bin/python2.7 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Is this error related to the version of python I an trying to use for the virtual environment?

Comment: It looks like your python was compiled with 4 byte encoding and the mkvirtualenv script (also written in python) is using your system python. That python looks like it was compiled with 2 byte encoding (I might have this reversed).

Comment: Can you try to create a virtualenv without using mkvirtualenv? I think some things that virtualenvwrapper are doing afterward are where the issues are. It might be easier to isolate that way.

Comment: One more idea: Do you have multiple pythons installed? It looks like it's picking up stuff in /usr/local/lib/. If you have multiple pythons, try getting rid of /usr/local/lib/python2.7, or at the very least removing it from PATH, PYTHONPATH, etc.